# How to convert command line switch to unicode Python2 and 3 compatible

Tags: python, argparse, six

I'm trying to make Argparse using unicode in both PY2 and PY3 preferably without complex constructs like `if six.PY2:` or `sys.version_info.major`. When it comes to using unicode for io operations or immediate string literals I know I have to use io/codecs or imports from `__futute__` to resolve these issues. However not sure what is the best approach for argparse. Currently I'm using this code:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argv_enc = sys.getfilesystemencoding()
parser.add_argument('url', type=lambda s: bytearray(s,argv_enc).decode(argv_enc))
```

I think it's incorrect because bytearray tries to decode ASCII and I don't need this step at all. Instead I'd like to decode `s` only if it's not already decoded.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't really an argparse issue, since a function that works as `type` would also work converting the `args.url`  string after parsing.  How about a simple `try/except` clause?

Comment: you're right, I just added `argparse` tag in case if someone knows a better way of doing the same stuff using argparse module. For now I decided to use `if six.PY2` approach.